# Pass TypeScript property from outside scope, into scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have the following TypeScript Code. When I try to change the properties of the class inside the anonymous functions, I can not because they are out of scope. Is there any way to pass them in so they can be changed?

```js
class PositionCtrl {


    //rectangles: Rectangle[];
    lat: number; long: number; rad: number;
    save() {
        alert("Settings Saved");
    }




    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {

        var tempLat: number = this.lat = 20;
        var tempLong: number = this.long = 20;
        var rad: number = this.rad = 1000;

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)


        function setRad(x) {
            this.$scope.position.rad = x;
        }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)),
            title: 'Some location'
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: this.rad,
            fillColor: '#AA0000',
            clickable: false
        });


        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    
        //Watches radius for changes
        $scope.$watch('position.rad', function () {





            circle.setRadius(Number(rad));
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
            console.log("done");

        });
        //Watches lat and long for changes
        $scope.$watchGroup(['position.lat', 'position.long'], function () {

              //THIS IS OUT OF SCOPE
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)));


            console.log("done");

        });


            
        //Click event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map = map, 'click', function (event) {
            marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            $scope.$apply(function () {
              
              //THIS IS OUT OF SCOPE
                this.lat = event.latLng.lat();
                this.Long = event.latLng.lng();
            })
            var test: number = 0;
            console.log(tempLong);
            test = Number(rad);
            circle.setRadius(test);
            console.log(rad);
            console.log(circle.getRadius());
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
        });



    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function (`(args) => body`) to preserve `this`:

```
   //Watches lat and long for changes
    $scope.$watchGroup(['position.lat', 'position.long'], () => {
        // OK
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)));
    });
```